# File dependency Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I am a gmake user transitioning to Gradle. I have a multi-project structure, where one sub-project is a Java project and the other a home-brewed language. The home-brewed language does not use any Gradle plugins. Now I want to add a task that runs a Java program to generate XML when any of my home-brewed source files have been modified. In make, I would just declare a dependency on inputFile.mine or *.mine next to the target name, but I could not easily find how to do this basic thing with Gradle. Currently, I force the task to always execute using the potentially ugly work-around below. I want to replace this with some dependsOn *.mine . The Gradle user guide has a whole chapter dedicated to explaining different ways of specifying files, but I did not see how to declare a dependency.

```
task generateXML(type: Exec) {
generateXML.getOutputs().upToDateWhen({false}) // Force it to execute always
executable("java.exe")
args("-jar", "resources/generateXml.jar", "src/inputFile.mine") 
}
```

Thanks for helping a newbie out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define task inputs and outputs in Gradle.

For example:

```
task generateXML(type: Exec) {
  inputs.file ("src/inputFile.mine")
  executable("java.exe")
  args("-jar", "resources/generateXml.jar", "src/inputFile.mine")
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html and https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html for more information.

Side note: When you run your build with `-i`, Gradle will tell you what has happened during the up-to-date check.

Comment: Thank you! These references and example are exactly what I needed. In particular, Section 17.9. "Skipping tasks that are up-to-date" addresses the issue.